# Github collaborator notifications

Tags: github

If I remove someone from a Github repository as collaborator, will they get notified that they are removed as a collaborator? Thank you for response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. They won't get any notifications from Github. I have had removed some collaborators on my repositories as well and they did not receive any notifications from it. They will only be notified if you add them to the repository.